# How to Delete many Cron Job Log files in Cpanel

Tags: cron, cpanel, cron-task, kubernetes-cronjob

How Do I delete about 5,000 Cron job log files in a Cpanel. 
The files are so many and I need to remove those files with the name shown in the image link attached here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScnCR.png